# Github Pull Request to base branch show commits from branch after merging base branch to current

Tags: github

I based my branch `my_branch` on a base branch `base`.

I made my changes and mean while the base branch has been changed and committed.

I created a pull request from `my_branch` into `base`.
It show the changes from the commits on the `base` after I created mine.

I tried to merged the base into my current and it didn't help.

I still see the base branch commits.

Why is it and how can I resolve this? I only want to show my changes on the PR..

Thank you